# Is low self-esteem, a brain chemical imbalance problem, rather than a personality defect, and can't be fixed by any amount of counselling/self-help?

Tags: psychiatry, psychology, brain, therapy, medication

I am asking this question because I recently observed something within myself:-

I think I used to be a Borderliner plus Bipolar. I was very sensitive, and slightest of events will either induce mania in me or will just thrash me into severe depression and low self-esteem.

But since I am taking a certain medication, I have observed that I am now not experiencing above mentioned behavior within me. I am much more resilient to criticism.

Comment: It depends on the reason for the low self-esteem.  If the feelings are a result of depression for example, brain chemical/hormonal imbalances can play a part, but it can be nothing to do with chemicals/hormones.  Another aspect to this is that medications which affect the chemicals/hormones can assist in the efficacy of therapy.

Comment: It sounds to me like this is a different (complicated) way of asking whether low self-esteem can be caused by anything else than chemical imbalances in the brain. In the remaining parts of your question you are already presuming an answer.

Comment: This is a good question which sparked a separate one linked to this at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/20253

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low self-esteem can be the result of severeal things, implying depression and other mental disorders, past experiences (harassement for example). We **can** "fix" low self-esteem through non-drug therapy, but sometimes we **can't**. There is no fixed answer, it varies from person to person.

---

**My personnal experience :** 
I am a schizoaffective and asperger person, for me, self-esteem is something really instable because of depressive/hypomaniac phases and schizophrenic symptoms. It is not something that I can control, except with high medication.

**Sources and readings :**

- [Low self-esteem and psychiatric patients: Part I – The relationship between low self-esteem and psychiatric diagnosis](https://annals-general-psychiatry.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1475-2832-2-2)
- [Low Self-Esteem Is Related to Aggression, Antisocial Behavior, and Delinquency](http://healthyselfesteem.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/low-self-esteem-aggression.pdf)
- [Self-Esteem and Adolescent Problems: Modeling Reciprocal Effects](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2095720?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is more of a comment than an answer (something you can do once you have contributed a bit more to this site), since we expect answers to include references/citations to back up claims. Therefore, this might be turned into a comment.